# PHP How to change value of serialized data and write to db

Tags: php, serialization

This is my serialized data and i want to remove one of key's value.

```
{a:9:{s:7:"320x480";s:16:"en_1_320x480.jpg";s:7:"320x568";s:16:"en_2_320x568.jpg";s:7:"360......
```

If i do like this

```
$pcon = unserialize($body);
$pcon[$_POST['id']]='';
$body = serialize($pcon);
```

It will be

```
{s:7:"320x480";s:16:"";s:7:"320x568...
```

I want like this

```
{s:7:"320x480";N;s:7:"320x568...
```

Answer (score 0):

It must like this

```
$pcon[$_POST['id']]=Null;
```